# Unable to batch insert records into MSSQL DB using GORM: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

Obtaining below the `error` on batch insert os records using GORM for MSSQL

```
reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value
```

```
var users = []User{{Name: "jinzhu1"}, {Name: "jinzhu2"}, {Name: "jinzhu3"}}
DB.Create(&users)

for _, user := range users {
  user.ID // 1,2,3
}
```

```
Obtaining db table not found error: mssql: Invalid object name 'dbo.at_' for below
```

```
DB.Model(&User{}).Create(map[string]interface{}{
  "Name": "jinzhu", "Age": 18,
})

// batch insert from `[]map[string]interface{}{}`
DB.Model(&User{}).Create([]map[string]interface{}{
  {"Name": "jinzhu_1", "Age": 18},
  {"Name": "jinzhu_2", "Age": 20},
})
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: no, havent found the solution yet

Comment: what version of gorm are you using ? I assume this is only a 2.0 feature as I am also getting it and currently using 1.9

Comment: i am using 1.9.16

Comment: Batch inserts are available only from Gorm 2 onwards. Upgrading should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I met a same problem:

```
panic in handler: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value
```

and I solved it by upgrading gorm to v2